# What is the Keystore of our project in cmd for getting SH1 key? give me examples

Tags: android

What is the Keystore of our project in cmd for getting SH1 key? give me examples...

\:keytool-v-list keystore **"debug.keystore"** -alias androiddebugkeystore -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 2):

```
See this
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
-keystore "C:\Users\amol\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | open
 ssl base64
 Enter keystore password:  android
I9D1n+1FRzdrk7EPsNde1JRojlE=
```